# Error message while saving a .pgf figure with LaTeX code on axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am having an error trying to save a .pfg using Pylab. The error comes from the xlabel, where I added some LaTeX commands:

```
title("$Ley \ de \ Snell \ de \ la \ reflexión$")
xlabel("$ \\theta_r \ [\\degree]$")
ylabel("$ \\theta_i \ [^{\\circ}]$")
legend(["$Datos \ exprimentales$","$Recta \ de \ ajuste$"])
```

The error I receive is the first one, and if I try to save it again, then I receive the second one:

[image]

It seems that the problem is comming from \\degree and \\circ, without them I can save it without a problem. However, the plot shows with no problem, even with these codes.

[image]

Any solution? Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

SOLVED: The problem was the use of non-stock LaTeX commands without importing the required packages previously. Instead of importing them, I decided to use a stock LaTeX command.

Comment: Can you try putting `r` before all the starting quotations `"` like `xlabel(r"$ \\theta_r \ [\\degree]$")`

Comment: I just tried that, it makes an error. I tried to delete one bar `\ ` of each command then it worked again, but I am having the same problem, it plots good but cant be saved. The `r` label seems to replace the second `\ ` I wrote.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: The best alternative in my opinion to get a degree is to use small o as a subscript as $^o$

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the key. I tried with a stock latex command that write something similar and it worked.

By the way, could you give me an example to include a LaTeX package in Python? I found many of them but noone works, so I guess I am doing something wrong, again.

Comment: I'm currently having problems running even valid latex, so I would also need to point you to existing solutions.

Comment: The alternative $^o$ is good aswell, but only for this example. It differs a little bit as I could see.